# Move reference overload for element access in containers?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

STL containers have two overloads for `operator[]`, one `const` and one `non-const` and two corresponding typedef.

```
template<class T>
struct vector{
      T* data_;
      using value_type = T;
      using reference = T&;
      using const_reference = T const&;
      reference operator[](int idx){return *(data_ + idx);}
      const_reference operator[](int idx) const{return *(data_ + idx);}
};
```

**In C++11, wouldn't for consistency make sense to have a r-value reference return as well?**

```
template<class T>
struct vector{
      T* data_;
      using value_type = T;
      using reference = T&;
      using const_reference = T const&;
      using move_reference = T&&;
      reference operator[](int idx) &{return *(data_ + idx);}
      const_reference operator[](int idx) const&{return *(data_ + idx);}
      move_reference operator[](int idx) &&{return *(data_ + idx);}
};
```

For that matter, this actually generalizes to `iterator` -> `const_iterator` -> `move_iterator`, which looks like an explosion of types and overloads for a simple container.

One could move from elements in a container:

```
void f(vector<ExpensiveType>&& v){
     ExpensiveType et = std::move(v)[0]; // v[0] is might moved here
}
```

I know that I could do `et = std::move(v[0])` in this example, but `std::move(v)[0]` is more generic because one can let the container handle the move in a more specific way (via the `operator[]&&`).

**Has something like this been discussed or implemented in some container-like class?**

---

@Praetorian suggests to return a value from the rvalue-ref qualified overload.

```
value_type operator[](int idx) &&{return std::move??(*(data_ + idx));}
```

Comment: Why would you want to return an rvalue reference instead of returning by value from the rvalue reference qualified overload? That's just asking for trouble. Consider `ExpensiveType&& et = std::vector<ExpensiveType>{...}[0];`, you have a dangling reference with your example.

Comment: @Praetorian Where is the dangling reference? In my code or in your comment? Even if so, an rvalue-ref qualified overload would be necessary. Actually, from your counter example, I can build a better example. `ExpT et = vector<ExpT>{a, b, c}[0]`. The only way to minimize copies (of `a`) is to have a rvalue-ref overload to `operator[]`. Do you agree?

Comment: It's in my example, you avoid it by initializing a value type instead of a reference type. Since there's no expectation that the object on which an rvalue ref qualified member function has been invoked will outlive the end of that expression, I would say you should default to returning by value from such overloads. (and you do need `move` in the return statement)